# Is it possible to have a type class for both constants and expressions in DSL?

Tags: haskell, dsl, functional-dependencies, type-families

Suppose, I have a DSL with computations in `LangL r a`. I might want to have functions work both with constants (`0 :: Int`, `"lala" :: String`) and DSL expressions (`LangL r a`). So, I implement a type class. However, any way I try to implement it, I stumble into problems.

Here's a minimal example of a problem when using type families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}

data LangL r a = LangL a
deriving instance Functor (LangL r)
deriving instance Applicative (LangL r)

class DSLEntity r a where
  type ValueOf a
  entityValue :: a -> LangL r (ValueOf a)

instance DSLEntity r (LangL r a) where
  type ValueOf (LangL r a) = a
  entityValue = id

instance DSLEntity r Int where
  type ValueOf Int = Int
  entityValue = pure

foo :: LangL r Int -> LangL r Int
foo m = entityValue (entityValue m)
```

GHC gives the following output:

```
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘r0’ arising from a use of ‘entityValue’
      prevents the constraint ‘(DSLEntity
                                  r (LangL r0 Int))’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        m :: LangL r Int (bound at temp.hs:25:5)
        foo :: LangL r Int -> LangL r Int
          (bound at temp.hs:25:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘r0’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance DSLEntity r (LangL r a)
          -- Defined at temp.hs:16:10
    • In the expression: entityValue (entityValue m)
      In an equation for ‘foo’: foo m = entityValue (entityValue m)
   |
temp.hs:25:22-34: error: …
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘r0’ arising from a use of ‘entityValue’
      prevents the constraint ‘(DSLEntity
                                  r0 (LangL r Int))’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
        m :: LangL r Int (bound at temp.hs:25:5)
        foo :: LangL r Int -> LangL r Int
          (bound at temp.hs:25:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘r0’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance DSLEntity r (LangL r a)
          -- Defined at /temp.hs:16:10
    • In the first argument of ‘entityValue’, namely ‘(entityValue m)’
      In the expression: entityValue (entityValue m)
      In an equation for ‘foo’: foo m = entityValue (entityValue m)
   |
```

The problem is clear. There is no dependency between `r` parameter of `LangL r a` and `r` parameter of `DSLEntity`. However, we cannot add such a dependency because for `Int` instance it actually does not exist.

I'm rather confused and would like to know if it's possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do. If not, why?

Comment: What is the meaning of `r`? Why do you need it at all?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It is needed for the DSL. To be exact, it's a reference type for mutable variables. Might be `IORef`/`TVar`/etc.

Comment: Somebody can always add `instance DSLEntity Foo (LangL Bar a)` and you cannot do much about it. So the dependency doesn't really exist, not just for `Int` but for `LangL r a` as well.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Yes, it doesn't. However, I would like it to. This piece of code is a proof that I tried, as this site requires. Still, I would like to know a way even if it differs a lot

Comment: Ben answered quite well, but I think the whole question smells a bit like an XY problem. Would `Num` and perhaps `IsString` instances for your DSL type get you the convenience you need?

Comment: @dfeuer, I don't really want to do `Num` stuff with `LangL` entities. I just want to treat constants of, say, type `Int` the same way I treat other expressions, yielding `Int`. I don't see how making `LangL` a `Num` instance would solve that.

Comment: It would only help if your real goal were to be able to write out numeric literals in your DSL directly as numbers, rather than needing to apply a constructor manually.

Comment: @dfeuer. It is my goal indeed. It might be not the best design, I'm just exploring possibilities

Comment: So if that's your goal, a `Num` instance might accomplish it. The only caveat is that your DSL will have to support `Num` methods. But then you can also do fun things producing expressions quite compactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
instance (r ~ r') => DSLEntity r' (LangL r a) where
```

instead of:

```
instance DSLEntity r (LangL r a) where
```

It's a little arcane what this actually does.

Your original instance declaration says that GHC can only use that instance when it can prove that the `r` in `LangL r a` is the same type in the argument and in the result of `entityValue`. But `entityValue :: a -> LangL r (ValueOf a)`, so any type at all can be used as the input (and require GHC to go looking for a matching instance). In particular, any `LangL r0 a` can appear as the input, even for non-matching `r`. So in `entityValue (entityValue m)`, the first one could be used at any `r0`, and the second will convert it back to the `r` used in the type of `foo`. Since GHC can't establish *which* `r` you're talking about in the middle, you get the problem that the ambiguous type variable prevents it from knowing which `DSLEntity` instance it should choose to resolve the constraint.

Whereas `instance (r ~ r') => DSLEntity r' (LangL r a)` says that this instance applies for **any** types `r` and `r'`, but using it adds the constraint that `r` and `r'` are equal. This sounds the same as just writing `instance DSLEntity r (LangL r a)`, but it actually isn't because of the rule that GHC doesn't consider constraints when choosing instances, only afterwards. Now GHC doesn't need to prove that `r` and `r'` are equal in order to choose this instance, it will choose the instance any time the second parameter of a `DSLEntity` constraint looks like `LangL _ _`, and then after that it will know that in order to typecheck the constraint `r ~ r'` must hold, so it will go ahead and assume that (if it's possible; otherwise you get a type error).

You can see the difference pretty clearly by looking at the type of `entityValue . entityValue`. With your original instance, you get:

```
λ :t entityValue . entityValue 
entityValue . entityValue
  :: (DSLEntity r1 (LangL r2 (ValueOf a)), DSLEntity r2 a) =>
     a -> LangL r1 (ValueOf a)
```

And with the new instance you get this:

```
λ :t entityValue . entityValue 
entityValue . entityValue
  :: DSLEntity r a => a -> LangL r (ValueOf a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your detailed answer helps a lot to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to give GHC a little help with the intermediate type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}

foo :: forall r. LangL r Int -> LangL r Int
foo m = entityValue (entityValue m :: LangL r Int)
```